# How to combine 2 datasets to make this dataset?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to ask you how to combine 2 datasets to the merged one that would look like this:
[image: merged dataset]

I need to merge those datasets:

| Shop | Segment | Sales 2018 | Sales 2019 | Evolution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Online | 3856 | 4383 | 14% |
| B | Offline | 5719 | 6819 | 19% |
| C | Online | 7894 | 9197 | 17% |
| C | Offline | 1615 | 2153 | 33% |
| B | Online | 5856 | 4028 | -31% |
| A | Offline | 9667 | 8188 | -15% |

And this:

| Shop | Segment | Sales 2018 | Sales 2019 | Evolution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Offline | 1923 | 1953 | 2% |
| B1 | Offline | 3749 | 4763 | 27% |
| C1 | Online | 4443 | 4065 | -9% |
| A1 | Online | 811 | 932 | 15% |
| C1 | Offline | 1938 | 2451 | 26% |
| B1 | Online | 3951 | 3348 | -15% |

The A1 should be exactly under A, B1 under B etc. I would like also to remove columns shop and segment from ouput dataset

P.s. it is only sample of datasets, both 2 can have different orders, but A1 should be under A, B1 under B etc. I wonder if it is possible to do this :)

Thank you in advance!

UPDATE:
The expected output:
[image: output]

UPDATE:
The real dataset 2:

| Shop | Segment | Sales 2018 | Sales 2019 | Evolution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | Offline | 1923 | 1953 | 2% |
| B1 | Offline | 3749 | 4763 | 27% |
| C1 | Online | 4443 | 4065 | -9% |
| A1 | Online | 811 | 932 | 15% |
| C1 | Offline | 1938 | 2451 | 26% |
| B1 | Online | 3951 | 3348 | -15% |
| D1 | Offline | 5331 | 4371 | -18% |
| ABD1 | Online | 2193 | 2881 | 31% |
| BC1 | Offline | 4773 | 4773 | 0% |
| AQ1 | Online | 9100 | 9325 | 2% |
| DEP1 | Offline | 5741 | 5611 | -2% |
| KQ1 | Online | 5998 | 5066 | -16% |
| LP2 | Offline | 1073 | 1029 | -4% |

The real dataset 1:

| Shop | Segment | Sales 2018 | Sales 2019 | Evolution |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Online | 3856 | 4383 | 14% |
| B | Offline | 5719 | 6819 | 19% |
| C | Online | 7894 | 9197 | 17% |
| C | Offline | 1615 | 2153 | 33% |
| B | Online | 5856 | 4028 | -31% |
| D | Offline | 9667 | 8188 | -15% |
| ABD | Online | 5132 | 5183 | 1% |
| AQ | Offline | 7005 | 7164 | 2% |
| BC | Offline | 8122 | 8600 | 6% |
| LP | Online | 2517 | 2429 | -3% |
| KQ | Online | 7856 | 7013 | -11% |
| DEP | Offline | 10392 | 9548 | -8% |

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` and `unstack`:

```
(pd.concat([df1, df2])
   .set_index(['Shop', 'Segment'])
   .unstack(-1)
   .swaplevel(axis=1)
   .sort_index()
   .rename(columns={'Evolution': 'Z'}, level=1)
   .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=[False, True])
   .rename(columns={'Z': 'Evolution'}, level=1)
)
```

output:

```
Segment     Online                         Offline                     
        Sales 2018 Sales 2019 Evolution Sales 2018 Sales 2019 Evolution
Shop                                                                   
A             3856       4383       14%       9667       8188      -15%
A1             811        932       15%       1923       1953        2%
B             5856       4028      -31%       5719       6819       19%
B1            3951       3348      -15%       3749       4763       27%
C             7894       9197       17%       1615       2153       33%
C1            4443       4065       -9%       1938       2451       26%
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it did not work :( The order of first and second datasets is not the same as in the table(question). May be it is possible to reorder merged dataset?

Comment: Can you provide the expected output (with real numbers)?

Comment: Somehow it prints something like:
A
B
C
A1
B1
C1
etc.

Comment: Please provide the real dataset, it works fine for me with this one

Comment: @nikita1221 so you just want to remove everything that is not A/A1/B/B1/C/C1?

Comment: No, I would like to make that one: A/A1, B/B1, DEP/DEP1 etc.

Comment: Well, this is already working fine. All the X1 are sorted after the X. I tested with the new dataset. Anyway, I provided the most complicated part of the problem. Please open a new question if you have issue with sorting, this does not belong to this question in my opinion.

Comment: For information this is the order that my code outputs with the updated data: `['A', 'A1', 'ABD', 'ABD1', 'AQ', 'AQ1', 'B', 'B1', 'BC', 'BC1', 'C', 'C1', 'D', 'D1', 'DEP', 'DEP1', 'KQ', 'KQ1', 'LP', 'LP2']`, which matches the requested order

Comment: May be it is because of indexes? Before there were some manipulations with those 2 datasets and indexes are: [5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 7, 0, 8, 6] [5, 2, 3, 4, 1, 7, 0, 6, 8]